# How can i plot float list

Tags: python

I wanted to plot simple distribution of these data with years, but when plotting using the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.ylim(2000,2020)
plt.plot (years,Global)
```

it didn't show any plots, in addition, the global list when looking for its length it was read as one element, i couldn't understand why?

```
[0     1290.6
 1     1256.0
 2     1198.1
 3     1128.4
 4     1070.9
 5     1011.7
 6      975.7
 7      945.5
 8      954.1
 9      885.9
 10     832.8
 11     805.4
 12     736.3
 13     715.2
 14     677.6
 15     647.1
 16     642.0
 17     582.1
 Name: Global, dtype: float64]
```

Comment: Is there any error or warning? if there is, please state in question.

Comment: can you please create sample pandas dataframe of Year and Global variable ? so we understand data well.

Comment: Also when formatting code please select the code area and use ctrl+k

Comment: add a `plt.show()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.

You have set ylim as 2000 to 2020 and when you do `plt.plot(years,Global)`, the Global list is plotted on the y axis and since none of the values in the Global list are in the given range(i.e 2000 to 2020) they aren't plotted on the graph.

The simplest method is to use yticks instead of ylim. ylim specifies the range of values on the y axis, whereas yticks specifies the value data points on the y axis.

Try this -

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
years = list(range(2000,2018))
Global = [1290.6,1256.0, 1198.1, 1128.4,  1070.9, 1011.7, 975.7, 945.5, 954.1, 885.9, 832.8, 805.4, 736.3,715.2, 677.6, 647.1, 642.0, 582.1]
plt.plot (Global,years)
plt.yticks(years)
plt.show()
```

Here I have taken the years on y axis with values 2000 to 2017 (I chose 17 years as your Global list has 17 elements and to plot two lists, they must have same number of elements) and set the yticks as the elements of list years.

Output -

[image: Plot]

I hope this helped you ..